# How to programmatically set ng-required to true (via controller) in angularjs form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-scope

I have a form and an input field, I want to make it required based on specific condition, but I can't change the html page, I have to set the make the field required to true dynamically inside the controller. Does angular provide any way to do set an input field to required field.

Also i don't have attribute

```
ng-required
```

present for the input field.

Comment: Perhaps two input fields switched with ng-hide will make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand that you are not able to change the HTML page?  Can you set the ng-required attribute to something in $scope?

e.g. HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-required="value">
```

e.g. Controller

```
$scope.value = true;
```

If you can't set it via a $scope variable, it might not be possible due to the ng-required not referring to anything.  If you need a more dynamic method of returning true/false you can set ng-required to a function and have the function return true or false based on whatever you want the function to check.  Can't help more without more information, sorry.

Comment: i can't add ng-required inside html

Comment: Does the input have an id or some sort of class you can set an attribute to it using angular.element or jquery? if you can't change the page at all, then I'm sorry, I don't think there is a way to change that.